# NodeMCU http server stopped working

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I was successful at running nodemcu-httpserver by Marcos Kirsch on ESP02.
Now I've got a new ESP12e. 
I have flushed the same nodemcu and uploaded the same files, same program to it.

But when I run it and call the server, nothing happens. Nothing, like it was not there, yet the device still operates. It can list files, for instance.

Any reason why? Any way to diagnose that?

My current version of firmware is:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: b580bfe79e6e73020c2bd7cd92a6afe01a8bc867
    SSL: false
    modules: adc,enduser_setup,file,gpio,http,net,node,pwm,spi,tmr,tsl2561,uart,wifi,ws2801
 build  built on: 2016-07-09 10:38
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.1(e67da894)

> = wifi.sta.getip()
192.168.8.104   255.255.255.0   192.168.8.1
> start_httpserver()
nodemcu-httpserver running at http://192.168.8.104:80
```

Comment: What answer do you get on the client? A HTTP error or an error from the client? Can you send `telnet 192.168.8.104 80`? You could build a firmware with DEBUG=true and see if you get any hints.

Comment: @MarcelStör I'm geting "Connection timed out". It's like the device wan't there (also using putty). But I can confirm that it correctly works as http client as I could run http.get and got data from some site in internet.

Comment: Can you rule out that a network component (e.g. router, firewall) between your client and your server is dropping/blocking the inbound connection?

Comment: What if you start a simple HTTP server yourself instead? Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NodeMCU#HTTP_server

Comment: @MarcelStör Thank you marcel for a good hint. My AP started to block intranet communication. Huawei cube ... ehh...